# Fatal error when activating my custom wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

When i try and activate my custom plugin i get the error shown below but this makes no sense to me as it seems ok code wise.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Functionality\AlterTable\AlterTableComments' not found in C:\wamp64\www\wp-content\plugins\functionality\example.php on line 130
```

incase your wondering this is on line 130:

```
new AlterTableComments;
```

Comment: This simply means the class you are trying to initiate is not defined. Did you write the plugin yourself?

Comment: try to use class name with namespace prefix
`$a = '\namespacename\classname';
$obj = new $a;`
see http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.dynamic.php

Comment: `$a = '\PethouseukFunctionality\AlterTable\AlterTableComments'; $obj = new $a;`

Comment: Add code snippet to your question if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I conclude form your comments is `pethouseuk-functionality.php`

```
include 'AlterTableComments.php';

use PethouseukFunctionality\AlterTable;

$a = 'PethouseukFunctionality\AlterTable\test';
$a();  // function call

$b = 'PethouseukFunctionality\AlterTable\AlterTableComments';
$c = new $b; // new object

$c->yourfunction('test'); // Method call
```

Another file AlterTableComments.php

```
<?php

namespace PethouseukFunctionality\AlterTable;

interface AlterTableInterface{

    function yourfunction($param);

}

class AlterTableComments implements AlterTableInterface{
    function yourfunction($param){
        var_dump($param);
    }
}

function test(){
    echo 'this is test ';
}
```

**Result:** 
this is test string(4) "test"

Comment: Hope this helps